# What open source software should I use to write scripts to test for no errors on a site?

Tags: testing, automation

What open source software should I use to write scripts to test for no errors on a site?

Could I / we write something better ourselves if there a limited number of goals outlined?
 - yet flexible enough to take on new rules etc.

The only consistent response we want is no errors, period.

I know Java, ASP and scripting languages if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is one good Website automated testing tool. It allows macros as well as hand-written scripts. Also has support for Firefox browser.

Understanding of Java should suffice.

You can check it out at http://seleniumhq.org/

Another good open source alternative is HTMLUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/
Again this requires knowledge of Java

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the [robotframework](http://www.robotframework.org), combined with the [selenium2library](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library) keyword library. It lets you write very human-readable tests and gives very nice reports. It integrates nicely with jenkins. Robotframework is written in python, and can be extended with python. It allows you to create data driven tests, BDD-style tests, or more traditional procedural tests.